# What is the correct way to get the color of a font from a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on redesigning a site, I need to get the font color of some paragraphs from the original site and then use them on the new site, I use Firefox devtool and first I have seen if in Typography I could get this information but I get useful information but not the color, then I have been using the color picker in the inspector tab but usually it is difficult for me to know what is the correct color, for example look at the following images

[image]

[image]

What is the correct way to get the color of a font from a site?

Comment: Have you tried examining the CSS ? [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS)

Comment: You can right click and inspect the page. Identify the element correctly and click on it. Check the right side of the developer tool window for css styles, and analyse which class (or inline style) is setting the color. There you will get the exact color of the element..

Comment: thanks guys, so simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the browsers "inspect" function to find the color the developer/designer set.

1. In chrome/firefox you right click on the paragraph/text you want the color from and choose "inspect (element)" in the context menu (using windows, but probably same in macOS).
2. Then a new windows/sidebar pops up. There you have to go into the "Styles" tab/section and look for "color: ...." there you will find the color code you're looking for.